# Excel Formula IF/AND with MIN Calculating Due Dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm creating a spreadsheet for payment plans. I am trying to create a formula to calculate the due date based on the $ amount and enrollment date. I want the formula to calculate for different tiers of the plan, which is where I'm running into problems. Here is the criteria:

(non low income)

Amount Due: $1-$150, Timeline: 6 weeks

Amount Due: $151-$300, Timeline: 10 weeks

Amount Due: $301-$500, Timeline : 12 weeks

Amount Due: $501-700, Timeline: 14 weeks

Amount Due $701-$1000, Timeline: 18 weeks

(low income)

<=$500/$25(installment)= # of months (max 18 months)

> =$501/$50(installment)= # of months (max 18 months)

Here is the formula i have which only works for the $501/$25 installment part and the non low income part: =IF(AND(B2="Y"),MIN(D2+546,(((C2/25)*30)+D2)),IF(AND(C2>=1,C2<=150),D2+6*7,IF(AND(C2>=151,C2<=300),D2+10*7,IF(AND(C2>=301,C2<=500),D2+12*7,IF(AND(C2>=501,C2<=700),D2+14*7,IF(AND(C2>=701),D2+18*7))))))

I can't seem to get both the $501/$50 to fit into the formula. The 546 represents 18 months in days. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhK4w.jpg)
[Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfsR6.jpg)
[Criteria2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpnnn.jpg)

Comment: Sometimes the best way is to use multiple intermediate columns, that way you can use simpler formulas.  Once the calculations all work you can use the hide column function so that you don’t need to see the intermediate calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(B2="Y",IF(C2<=500,MIN(D2+546,(((C2/25)*30)+D2)),MIN(D2+546,(((C2/50)*30)+D2))),IF(C2<=150,D2+6*7,IF(C2<=300,D2+8*7,IF(C2<=500,D2+12*7,IF(C2<=700,D2+14*7,D2+18*7)))))`

I have simplified some terms and adjusted the timeline for $151-$300 to agree with your table (`8*7` instead of `10*7`), but the only thing you were really missing was the `IF(C2<=500,MIN(D2+546,(((C2/25)*30)+D2)))),MIN(D2+546,(((C2/50)*30)+D2)))` portion, as you needed to check the amount owed if low income.

I left the multiplication terms in this, but if you have a large spreadsheet of these formulas I recommend replacing them with actual values, such as replacing `+8*7` with `+42`.  Even little  calculations can add up to slow down a spreadsheet.

However, while I'm not a financial expert, the use of 30 days to equal a month seems imprecise.  You may want to check out the use of `EDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the formula and use some other functions to return the desired amount to add to the date:

```
=D2+IF(B2="Y",MIN(546,(C2/((C2>500)*25+25))*30),LOOKUP(C2,{0,151,301,501,701},{6,10,12,14,18})*7)
```

So if `Y`, then we take the minimum of 546 days and the days returned by `(C2/((C2>500)*25+25))*30)`.

`(C2>500)` will return `1` if true and `0` if false which then is multipled by 25 and added to 25 to return either `50` or `25` to the denominator.

If `N` then the Lookup will happen which since it is relative will return the correct number of weeks based on where the value lands on the first array.

[image]

Comment: In `{0,151,201,501,701}`, I think that the third term should be 301 to match the provided table.

Answer (score 1):

@Rey Juna & @Scott Craner, thank you so much! I ended up using:

=IF(B2="Y",IF(C2<=500,MIN(EDATE(D2,18),(((C2/25)*30)+D2)),MIN(EDATE(D2,18),(((C2/50)*30)+D2))),IF(C2<=150,D2+42,IF(C2<=300,D2+70,IF(C2<=500,D2+84,IF(C2<=700,D2+98,D2+126)))))

Thanks for also notices my error on the table, the snip img was actually incorrect, so I've updated that. I wasn't successful using EDATE to calculate the month with the division, but I was able to use it as the 18 month cap. In my case 30 days is fine, because I have a generous grace period for due bills.